# merge partial duplicate rows in a table

Tags: awk, merge

Input is a settings file with multiple rows separated by tab.

```
h1 h2 h3 x  y      h4 h5 h6 h7
a  b  c  h4 true
a  b  c  h5 false 
a  b  d  h4 false
m  n  o  h6 true
m  n  o  h7 false
p  q  r  h4 true
```

Output is below.

```
h1 h2 h3  h4    h5    h6    h7
a  b  c   true  false
a  b  d   false
m  n  o               true  false
p  q  r   true
```

How can I achieve this ? I am trying some loops using awk with my limited knowledge but I am out of ideas.

```
awk -F'\t' '($1!=old1 || $2!=old2 || $3!=old3) && NR>2 
    {
        for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
            print a[i];
    } 
    {
        old1=$1;old2=$2;old3=$3;
        for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
        {
            a[i]= $i;
        }
    } 
    END{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print a[i];}' $tmpfile1
```

Comment: This sounds like a homework question. Perhaps one of the other StackOverflow sites could help? This one is primarily focussed on Ubuntu-specific topics 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following in GNU awk - with a 2D array:

```
$ gawk '
  BEGIN {
    OFS=FS="\t"
  }
  NR==1 {
    print "h1","h2","h3","h4","h5","h6","h7"
    next
  }
  {
    a[$1 FS $2 FS $3][$4] = $5
  }
  END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"
    for (k in a) {
      print k, a[k]["h4"],a[k]["h5"], a[k]["h6"], a[k]["h7"]
}
  }
' file
h1      h2      h3      h4      h5      h6      h7
a       b       c       true    false
a       b       d       false
m       n       o                       true    false
p       q       r       true
```

Comment: Thanks this is great. Its almost working except that h4, h5, h6, h7 column values are left aligned which means if the element is not present then empty space is not getting printed and it is overwritten by the next element on the right.